# Node Express Session Count

Tags: node.js, express

I have an application where I need to limit the number of active connections, and the most logical way of doing this to me, would be to simply count the number of active sessions.

I have searched for "node express session count" but did not find anything useful.

Is it possible to get the number of open sessions in node express ?

The alternative would be to save the IP address of each connected client, but the problem with this method is that the ip address would need to be manually removed from the datastore.

I guess if I use redis as the data store, I could use expire to achieve something similar.

```
set ip.192.168.42.1 true
expire ip.192.168.42.1 60
ttl ip.192.168.42.1
etc etc
```

Or is there a better way ?

## EDIT

I have tried the suggestion of using MemoryStore but I can't seem to figure out how to use it ??

```
    var express = require("express");
    var MemoryStore = express.session.MemoryStore;
    MemoryStore.prototype.length = function(fn) {
      fn(null, Object.keys(this.sessions).length);
    };

    MemoryStore.length(function(len) {
      console.log('sessions:'+len);
    });
```

Comment: Side note, if you're hosting on a Unix/Linux server you can easily limit this at the system level.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `Store.length(fn)` method. In the default Connect memory storage, it's written like this:

```
MemoryStore.prototype.length = function(fn) {
  fn(null, Object.keys(this.sessions).length);
};
```

So you would call it like this:

```
store.length(function(len) {
  // we have len number of sessions
});
```

Comment: So.. where does `store` come from? I am looking at code that does `var session = require('express-session'); ... express().use(session({...}))`... How do I get the `store` from the `session`?

Answer (score 0):

I am well aware of how old this post is but I thought I would share my way, as this comes up as the top result as I was trying to figure it out.

This what I did and it seems to be working.

So if you are using MySQLStore & Express Session you can approach it like this,

Add activeUsers to your options(app/index.js):

```
var options = {
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: 3306,
    user: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASS,
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    activeUsers: 0
};
```

On your login.js add:

```
 req.sessionStore.options.userCount += 1
```

And on your logout:

```
req.sessionStore.options.userCount += 1
```

Now I am not sure if on session timeout if this will return back to 0 or not, but I would assume that it does. And then just create a app.local that refers to the userSession count